# In Android, Custom Adapter code won't work when i set different colors to my listview rows?

Tags: android, listview

I have a small problem to set color to my listview rows. I used the below code (for Adapter) to set color for my listiview. I put two colors in to the array it works good. Now i wish to add 5 colors in my list. But this code won't works. How can i do this.

**Custom_List_Adapter.java**

```
private class Custom_List_Adapterextends BaseAdapter {
//Defining the background color of rows. The row will alternate between green light and green dark.
private int[] colors = new int[] { 0xAAf6ffc8, 0xAA538d00, 0xAAf6ddc8, 0xAA238d00, 0xAA788d00 };
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

//The variable that will hold our text data to be tied to list.
private String[] data;

public Custom_List_Adapter(Context context, String[] items) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

//A view to hold each row in the list
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

// A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
// to findViewById() on each row.
ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headline);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
    // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
    holder.text.setText(data[position]);

    //Set the background color depending of  odd/even colorPos result
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

   return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Explain "Code wont work"

Comment: Here is [reference for you][1]. Try this   



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065160/how-can-we-design-the-list-view-layout

Comment: i tried this but it won't work guys

Comment: As previously requested.. tell us **how** it's not working.  Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help us at all.  What is the problem?  Is it crashing?  Is it all one color?  Post LogCat information if there are errors shown there.  Help us to help you.

Comment: Barak:  I clearly mentioned I put two colors in to the array it works good. Now i wish to add 5 colors in my list. But this code won't works.